# Issues with coldfusion query function call inside a query loop

Tags: coldfusion

I have a query loop and inside that loop, I make a cfc function call to return a second query. It's doing weird things with the display:

In the example below, instead of making a function call to obtain the second query, I create a simple loop. This displays fine. [View the actual page here](http://scrapbookcentral.01dev.co.nz/quarterlyCalendar.cfm)

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfif qCal.recordcount>
        <a class="control" onClick="return hs.getExpander(this).printHtml()" href="##">Print</a>
    </cfif>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
        <cfloop query="qCal">
            <tr>
                <td align="middle" valign="top" style="width:150px;">
                    <a title="View full-sized image" onclick="return hs.expand(this)" href="/images/classes/#qCal.image#" class="highslide"><img src="/images/classes/#qCal.thumb#" class="resize2"></a></td>
                <td>
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" class="textNormal"><h2>#qCal.title#</h2></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="textNormal"><strong>Date:</strong></td>
                            <td class="textNormal"><strong>Time:</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <cfloop from="1" to="5" index="i"> <!--- basic loop --->
                            <tr>
                                <td>#i#</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </cfloop>   
                    </table>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </cfloop>
   </table> 
</cfoutput>
```

But, as soon as I make a function call to obtain a secondary query, inexplicable things happen with the display. [View the actual page here](http://scrapbookcentral.01dev.co.nz/quarterlyCalendar2.cfm) (which renders half-cooked html code).

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfif qCal.recordcount>
        <a class="control" onClick="return hs.getExpander(this).printHtml()" href="##">Print</a>
    </cfif>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
        <cfloop query="qCal">
            <cfsilent>
                <cfset qCalItems = o_system.getCalendarItems(
                      start=dateformat(vStartDate,"yyyy-mm-yy"),
                      end=dateformat(vEndDate,"yyyy-mm-yy"),
                      classID=qCal.classID,
                      forQuarterlyCalendar=true,
                      order_by="i.startDate")>
            </cfsilent>
            <tr>
                <td align="middle" valign="top" style="width:150px;">
                    <a title="View full-sized image" onclick="return hs.expand(this)" href="/images/classes/#qCal.image#" class="highslide"><img src="/images/classes/#qCal.thumb#" class="resize2"></a></td>
                <td>
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" class="textNormal"><h2>#qCal.title#</h2></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="textNormal"><strong>Date:</strong></td>
                            <td class="textNormal"><strong>Time:</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <cfloop query="qCalItems">
                            <tr bgcolor="#iif(qCalItems.CurrentRow MOD(2) eq 1,de('ffffff'),de('EFEFEF'))#">
                                <td>#DayOfWeekAsString(dayofweek(qCalItems.startDate))# #dateformat(qCalItems.startDate,"dd mmm yyyy")#</td>
                                <td>#qCalItems.startTime#-#qCalItems.endTime#</td>
                            </tr>
                        </cfloop>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </cfloop>
   </table> 
</cfoutput>
```

### UPDATE - CFC CODE ADDED

NOTE: Function returns either a struct or a query depending on the argument "forQuarterlyCalendar". It definitely returns a query object in this case. I have dumped the query out and confirm that it is a valid query object.

```
<cffunction name="getCalendarItems" access="remote" returntype="any" output="false" returnformat="json">
        <cfargument name="classID" type="any" required="false" default="">
        <cfargument name="forSelect" type="boolean" required="false" default="false">
        <cfargument name="forQuarterlyCalendar" type="boolean" required="false" default="false">
        <cfargument name="start" type="any" required="false" default="">
        <cfargument name="end" type="any" required="false" default="">
        <cfargument name="order_by" type="any" required="false" default="c.title">
        <cfargument name="sort_direction" type="any" required="false" default="asc">
        <cfargument name="json" type="boolean" required="false" default="true">
        <cfargument name="must_have_store_item" type="boolean" required="false" default="true">
        <cfset var qClass = 0>
        <cfset var realStart = "">
        <cfset var realEnd = "">
        <cfset var results = []>
        <cfset var vUrl = "">
        <cfset var vId = "">
        <cfset var vTitle = "">
        <cfset var vStart = "">
        <cfif len(trim(arguments.start))>
            <cfset realStart = EpochTimeToLocalDate(arguments.start)>
        </cfif>
        <cfif len(trim(arguments.end))> 
            <cfset realEnd = EpochTimeToLocalDate(arguments.end)>
        </cfif>

        <cfquery name="qClass" datasource="#application.datasource#">
            select  <cfif arguments.forSelect>
                        c.title, i.calendarItemID as id, convert(varchar, i.startDate, 103)+' '+i.startTime+'-'+i.endTime as text 
                    <cfelseif arguments.forQuarterlyCalendar>
                        c.description, i.calendarItemID as id, i.startDate, i.startTime, i.endTime 
                    <cfelse>
                        i.calendarItemID, i.startDate, i.startTime, i.endTime
                        ,c.classID, c.title, c.description, c.price, c.places, c.exclusive, c.discounted, c.url
                        ,s.storeItemID 
                    </cfif>
            from calendarItem i
            <cfif arguments.must_have_store_item>
                join storeItem s on s.entityID = i.calendarItemID and s.storeItemTypeID = 3 
            </cfif>
            join class c on c.classID = i.classID and c.active=1
            where i.active=1
            <cfif isnumeric(arguments.classID)>
                and i.classID = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.classID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
            </cfif>
            <cfif len(trim(arguments.start))>
                <cfif arguments.forQuarterlyCalendar>
                    and i.startDate >= <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.start#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
                <cfelse>
                    and i.startDate >= <cfqueryparam value="#dateformat(realStart,'yyyy-mm-dd')#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
                </cfif>
            </cfif>
            order by #arguments.order_by# #arguments.sort_direction#
        </cfquery>
        <cfif qClass.recordcount>
            <cfif not arguments.forSelect and not arguments.forQuarterlyCalendar>
                <cfloop query="qClass">
                    <cfset vUrl = qClass["url"]>
                    <cfset vId = qClass["storeItemID"]> 
                    <cfset vTitle = qClass["title"]>
                    <cfset vStart = GetEpochTimeFromLocal(qClass.startDate)>
                    <cfif not len(trim(url)) or len(trim(url)) is 0>
                        <cfset vUrl = "#application.webroot#/class_detail.cfm?id=#vId#">
                    </cfif>
                    <cfset s = structnew()>
                    <cfset s["id"] = vId>
                    <cfset s["url"] = vUrl>
                    <cfset s["title"] = vTitle>
                    <cfset s["start"] = vStart>
                    <cfset arrayappend(results, s)> 
                </cfloop>
            <cfelse>
                <cfset results = qClass>
            </cfif>
        </cfif>
        <cfif arguments.json>
            <cfcontent type="application/json">
        </cfif>
        <cfreturn results>
    </cffunction>
```

Comment: Please post the source code of the getCalendarItems() function within your o_system CFC. It *may* be necessary to post the entire CFC, including any base CFC it may extend, but start with that function, please.

Comment: Thanks for making me add the code. In the process, I discovered that the function was returning JSON formatted content. Passing "false" to the "json" argument makes it work properly.

Comment: I don't quite know why you've been voted down, but equally, you're not stating what your problem actually is.  You give us two URLs which display some mark-up, but you don't say something like "and this thing [which you then identify]: it's wrong".  I just see two web pages, with the one you're saying is wrong looking a lot better than the "control".  What's the actual problem?  State it as "I expect [x], but I get [y]".

Comment: Didn't realise there were so many precious people on this forum. Happy to provide whatever information is missing. When you're formatting code nicely and giving example pages, it's often easy to miss something.

Comment: I didn't get what is your question, actually

Comment: I don't think it's "being precious" to suggest that it would help if you articulated what your problem is clearly.  That's all anyone has suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You need to var scope 's':

```
<cfset s = structnew()>
```